# Typescript clarification on index types and mapped types

Tags: typescript

I have an interface that defines an object that can be used for passing command line arguments to an application:

```
type argumentPrimitive = string | number | Date | boolean;

export type IApplicationArguments = {
    [key: string]: argumentPrimitive | argumentPrimitive[];
}
```

I also have an interface that can optionally replace a value with an object that has configuration information about that argument:

```
export type IApplicationArgumentsConfiguration<T extends IApplicationArguments> = {
    readonly [P in keyof T]?: T[P] | CommandOption<T[P]>;
}
```

in my function that processes this I want to iterate through the values:

```
function parseCommands<T extends IApplicationArguments>(optionDefinition: IApplicationArgumentsConfiguration<T>): T {

    for (let propertyName in optionDefinition) {
        const propertyValue: argumentPrimitive | CommandOption<argumentPrimitive> =  optionDefinition[propertyName];
    }
}
```

This does not compile:

> Type 'IApplicationArgumentsConfiguration[keyof T]' is not assignable to type 'string | number | boolean | Date | CommandOption'.

Playground link with full error:

[Typescript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%0D%0Aexport%20interface%20CommandOption%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20sampleValue%3A%20T%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20argumentPrimitive%20%3D%20string%20%7C%20number%20%7C%20Date%20%7C%20boolean%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20type%20IApplicationArguments%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20argumentPrimitive%20%7C%20argumentPrimitive%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20type%20IApplicationArgumentsConfiguration%3CT%20extends%20IApplicationArguments%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20readonly%20%5BP%20in%20keyof%20T%5D%3A%20T%5BP%5D%20%7C%20CommandOption%3CT%5BP%5D%3E%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20parseCommands%3CT%20extends%20IApplicationArguments%3E(optionDefinition%3A%20IApplicationArgumentsConfiguration%3CT%3E)%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20for%20(let%20propertyName%20in%20optionDefinition)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20propertyValue%3A%20argumentPrimitive%20%7C%20CommandOption%3CargumentPrimitive%3E%20%3D%20%20optionDefinition%5BpropertyName%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D)

Is there a way to carry the mapped types through to the iteration code?

Comment: Why the explicit type annotation for `propertyValue` in the first place?

Comment: The function that I was passing this value to required that. I put the explicit in to aid debugging.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I had forgotten about the possibility of arrays.

correcting the code to this:

```
export interface CommandOption<T> {
    sampleValue: T;
}

type argumentPrimitive = string | number | Date | boolean;

type argumentTypes = argumentPrimitive | argumentPrimitive[];

export type IApplicationArguments = {
    [key: string]: argumentTypes;
}

export type IApplicationArgumentsConfiguration<T extends IApplicationArguments> = {
    readonly [P in keyof T]: T[P] | CommandOption<T[P]>;
}

function parseCommands<T extends IApplicationArguments>(optionDefinition: IApplicationArgumentsConfiguration<T>) {

    for (let propertyName in optionDefinition) {
        const propertyValue: argumentTypes | CommandOption<argumentTypes> =  optionDefinition[propertyName];
    }
}
```

makes it correctly compile.